# Accessing Single Cell with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = df[0].dropna(axis='columns')
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
del df['Name']
df = df.rename(columns={'Schedule': 'Period', 'Clssrm': 'Room'})
gk = df.groupby('Term') 
gk.get_group('S2'))

#Get Row 1 of Column Room
Room1 = gk.loc[1, 'Room']
```

I am hoping to access the first row of column "Room" using .loc but I get an error AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'loc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Is it possible to access cells by key and row number? for example df['Room'][1]?

Comment: Why do you need to use `groupby` if you have to call `get_group`? From the looks of it you could just do `df.loc[df["Term"].eq("S2"),"Room"].head(1)`.

Comment: this works but can you explain why?

Comment: This is just a very common use of [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Select by boolean array, choose column "Room", and get the first result by `head(1)`.

Comment: How do you get second, third, fourth result etc. head(2) contains the previous one for example

Comment: If you really insist on getting the values 1 by 1 (which is generally not a good idea), you can use [`.iat[num]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html). So `df.loc[df["Term"].eq("S2"),"Room"].iat[0]` for first value.